# Is there a way to increase distance between Header and first row?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I use a `DataGridView` to show some data. I changed `RowTemplate.DividerHeight` property to make a good visibility between rows. But the distance between Header of `DataGridView` and the first row is none. Can I increase this distance as the same as `RowTemplate.DividerHeight` value?

Edited: 
this is the definition for my `DataGridView`

```
myGridView.GridColor = Color.Black;
myGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
myGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 57);
myGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(641 - myGridView.Location.X - 10 - System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 490);
myGridView.Name = "myGridView";
myGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
myGridView.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 14);
myGridView.ColumnCount = 4;

myGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "NR REC";
myGridView.Columns[0].CellTemplate.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
myGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "RECORD NAME";
myGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "REG. NO";
myGridView.Columns[2].CellTemplate.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
myGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "VIEWER";
myGridView.Columns[3].CellTemplate.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
myGridView.Columns[0].Width = 60;
myGridView.Columns[2].Width = 60;
myGridView.Columns[3].Width = 80;
myGridView.Columns[1].Width = myGridView.Width - myGridView.Columns[0].Width - myGridView.Columns[2].Width - myGridView.Columns[3].Width;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in myGridView.Columns) {
    col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    col.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 20);
    col.HeaderCell.Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 20);
    col.HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
    col.DividerWidth = 0;
    col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            }
myGridView.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
myGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
myGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
myGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
myGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
myGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;

myGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 220, 20);
myGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;
myGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
myGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 50;
myGridView.RowTemplate.DividerHeight = 4;

myGridView.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
myGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
myGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight = 60;

myGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
myGridView.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
myGridView.TabIndex = 3;
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: As a hack you can have a dummy row at index `0` with `Height = 0`.

Comment: ColumnHeadersHeight ?

Comment: @Alex, yes, but if you scroll, it will disappear.

Comment: @TaW No, because it will increase the header hight only.That black line will not show.

Comment: @ValiMaties Please correct the image link in the question. Please avoid uploading images outside of stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry @RezaAghaei . I corrected it.

Comment: _.That black line will not show_ Huh? What black line are you talking about??? - Why not pick a Top alignment for the ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle?

Comment: @TaW "That black line" I'm referring to, is the divider from RowTemplate. Please read the post entirely, and don't give downvote... Ohhh. I wrote clearly in post : "Can I increase this distance as the same as RowTemplate.DividerHeight value?"

Comment: I have read the post and I repeat: The effect will be exactly the same. Did you try?

Comment: With those which give down vote for "nothing" , we don't learn C# anymore... I don;t know why some people are so pleased to click on down vote. It seems to look another place with people that want to REALLY explain and not to discourage  :(
I'm really very disappointed...

Comment: @ValiMaties I edited the question and removed the screenshot of the working solution. In fact it's not good idea to put the answer as part of the question. It makes the question a bit confusing and the answer nonsense. Instead you can click on the checkmark near the answer to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Ok @RezaAghaei, I did it... Thanks for your real help. Mans like you encourage us :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Helping other developers is my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can handle `CellPainting` event of `DataGridView` and draw the bottom border yourself. For example:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts);
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10))
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom,
                e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Reza This is the answer! :)

Comment: Cool! no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can change the distance by adding line codes:

```
dgv.Columns["col1"].HeaderCell.Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 5, 0, 0)
dgv.Columns["col2"].HeaderCell.Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 5, 0, 0)
```

Or i'd like to recomend to read in that link: [DATAGRIDVIEW PADDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/cell-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).

Comment: Hi @Prochu1991 . Thanks for your answer, but I don't think is the real answer, because it does not work as it has to be; padding header it will "eat" from header text, and the background is not black